# Core-data raises "The file has been changed by another application"

Tags: macos, core-data

When changing data in my core-data application, a error message comes up:

> The document “xyz.sqlite” could not be saved. The file has been
>   changed by another application.

In fact, there is no other application that has changed data. I observed in addition, that the undo management is not working well then.

Probably, I should not use more than one (unique?) Arraycontroller bound to the managedObjectContext for one entity ?

In my app, I use a classical master-detail relationship setup with 2 controllers for each entity - and 2 table views to display the data.

But, in addition I want to present a list of all details, where I can change the master. Therefore, I am using another Array controller bound to the same managedObjectContext. This one does not have a content set to the master, so it will have all detail objects. Using this approach makes it easy to manage the relationship in the associated tableview (by simply binding "selected Object" to the relationship of the detail) - but it seems to impact the app.

Does anybody else face this issue ? Any idea is welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Core Data on the Mac has never dealt well with multiple programmatic changes to the underlying data, especially in document-based apps. See, for example, [autosavesInPlace causes New Document save to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011042/autosavesinplace-causes-new-document-save-to-fail).

I think you're on the right track by using the same MOC for all of your views. If you use multiple MOCs, you ave the risk of getting the data out of sync between views. Using Cocoa Bindings on the array controllers ought to be keeping everything in sync.

Is there a situation where you're making programmatic changes to the data in the background? Those should probably be done in a child of the `viewContext`. Or take other steps to make sure they get synced to the `viewContext`.

Comment: So I will study viewContext , thank you for the hint - never came across this before. Yes, I change data in the background also. But even if I just use the tableviews (connected to the controllers) to change something, undo and save are quite confused.  By the way, I observed a quite interesting effect : if I change data in one view, I can see the changes in the other effecting directly.

Comment: OK, I have changed my app now. Only one array controller per entity ! The other array controllers are now bound to a fetchRequest instead of managedObjectContext. Now undo works fine. But still I have the message "The file has been changed by another application" after a while.

Comment: Any ideas? I still get this with 8.3.3

Comment: I must revise my previous conclusion. You CAN have several controllers for ONE entity. I succeeded in doing so. The message only comes up if I change items programmatically. The solution is to "tell" the controllers that   change.    Instead of   ` [theAccount setInternalAccount:accountVal];`  use:                    [theAccount willChangeValueForKey:@"internalAccount"];
[theAccount setInternalAccount:accountVal];
[theAccount didChangeValueForKey:@"internalAccount"];`